# Mysql inner joins where value in another table

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, inner-join

This is probably a very simple solution but i cannot get my head around the syntax.

I have my first table:

ratings

```
id
name
status
```

I then have another table

sectors

```
id
ratingid
name
```

So my basic query is **SELECT * FROM ratings** but what I need to do is select all records from ratings WHERE I then look at the sectors table WHERE the sectorid is passed from $_GET and only show records where the sectorid matches the $_GET

Does that make sense? Any help very appreciated..

Comment: It is the most basic join. Please take a tutorial first.

Comment: Learn [**joins**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM sectors INNER JOIN ratings
 ON sectors.rating_id = ratings.id
 WHERE sectors.id = $_GET['yoursectorid'];
```

I think this is what you're looking.

Comment: I guess we should not provide answers for such basic questions which clearly show no effort.